# WebRTC black screen

Tags: screen, webrtc

I have a problem. I want to learn WebRTC and bought a book. The problem is, the given code does not work. I thought that I made a mistake but I tried the given code of the book and there is the same problem.

I want to create a video communication between two video html elements. I already replaced some deprecated functions.
Currently, I just see myself (in "yours") and a black screen in "theirs". I should see me i both elements:

Screenshot: [WebRTC black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxFr9.png)

I do not know where the error is. Perhaps someone could help me?

Thank you!

**main.js**

```js
// Check whether the user has access to the getUserMedia API
function hasUserMedia() {
 
 navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
 
 return !!navigator.getUserMedia;
 
}

// Check whether the user has access to the RTCPeerConnection API
function hasRTCPeerConnection() {
 
 window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.msRTCPeerConnection;
 
 return !!window.RTCPeerConnection;
}

var yourVideo = document.querySelector('#yours'),
 theirVideo = document.querySelector('#theirs'),
 yourConnection, theirConnection;
 
if(hasUserMedia()) {
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false})
 .then(
  function(mediaStream) {
   
   // Giving the stream to the html object
   yourVideo.srcObject = mediaStream;
   
   if(hasRTCPeerConnection()) {
    startPeerConnection(mediaStream);
   } // End if(hasRTCPeerConnection())
   else {
    alert('Sorry, your browser does not support WebRTC.');
   } // End else if
   
  } // End function(mediaStream)
 ) // End getUserMedia().then()
 .catch(
  function(err) {
   alert('Sorry, we failed to capture your camera, please try again.');
   console.log(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
  } // End function(err)
 ) // End getUserMedia().catch()
} // End hasUserMedia()
else {
 alert('Sorry, your browser does not support WebRTC.');
} // End Else if(hasUserMedia())
 
function startPeerConnection(mediaStream) {
 var configuration = {
  // Uncomment this code to add custom iceServers
  "iceServers": [{"urls": "stun:stun.1und1.de"}, {"urls": "stun:stun.gmx.net"}, {"urls": "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19305"}, {"urls": "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19305"}]
 };
 
 yourConnection = new mozRTCPeerConnection(configuration);
 theirConncetion = new mozRTCPeerConnection(configuration);
 
 // Setup stream listening
 yourConnection.addStream(mediaStream);
 theirConncetion.ontrack = function (e) {
  theirVideo.srcObject = e.stream;
 };
 
 // Setup ice handling
 yourConnection.onicecandidate = function (event){
  if(event.candidate){
   theirConncetion.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
  }
 };
 
 theirConncetion.onicecandidate = function (event){
  if(event.candidate){
   yourConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate));
  }
 };
 
 yourConnection.createOffer(
  function (offer) {
   yourConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
   theirConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
   theirConnection.createAnswer(
    function (offer) {
     theirConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
     yourConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);
    }
   );
  }
 );
}

**index.html**
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta char="utf-8" />
  <title>Chapter 3</title>
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: #3D6DF2;
    margin-top: 15px;
   }
   video {
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid gray;
   }
   #container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
   }
   #yours {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
   }
   #theirs {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <video id="yours" autoplay></video>
  <video id="theirs" autoplay></video>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Old code from an old book. In an effort to stamp out old examples, allow me to offer some tips:

- Drop the `moz` prefix.
- Drop `window.msRTCPeerConnection`. It never existed.
- Your `hasUserMedia()` function polyfills the old `navigator.getUserMedia`, but your main code uses the newer `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`. Just check if the latter exists.
- Use `pc.ontrack = e => video.srcObject = e.streams[0];`, or if you want this to work in Chrome, use [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) or the older `pc.onaddtream = e => video.srcObject = e.stream;`
- Add failure-callbacks to your `createOffer` and `createAnswer` calls, or they [won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279635/webrtc-remotevideo-stream-not-working/38285718#38285718).

I see you use the newer promise-API for `getUserMedia`, but not for `RTCPeerConnection`. [Try](https://jsfiddle.net/aynr0k5q/):

```js
var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})
  .then(stream => pc1.addStream(video1.srcObject = stream))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));

pc1.onicecandidate = e => pc2.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => pc1.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);

pc2.ontrack = e => video2.srcObject = e.streams[0];
pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => console.log(pc1.iceConnectionState);
pc1.onnegotiationneeded = e =>
  pc1.createOffer().then(d => pc1.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
  .then(() => pc2.createAnswer()).then(d => pc2.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<video id="video1" width="160" height="120" autoplay muted></video>
<video id="video2" width="160" height="120" autoplay></video><br>
<div id="div"></div>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably replaced the deprecated onaddstream with ontrack (which so far is only supported in Firefox).
ontracks does not however have a e.stream property, try e.streams[0]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple. I found the answer here but I had to search harder over Google.
The solution is described there:
[onaddstream method is not executed after RTCPeerconnection object is instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795582/onaddstream-method-is-not-executed-after-rtcpeerconnection-object-is-instantiate/34796092)